# How to make a list of dicts from a list of values for a fixed set of keys

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list like this:

```
list = ['John', 18, 'Spain', 'Adam', 12, 'Hungary', 'Eve', 50, 'Greece', ...]
```

How can I make a list of dictionaries from it?

The expected result:

```
[{'name':'John', 'age':18, 'country':'Spain'},
 {'name':'Adam', 'age':12, 'country':'Hungary'}, 
 {'name':'Eve', 'age':50, 'country':'Greece'},
 ...]
```

Comment: by the way try not to use names like `list` as variable because they are reserved words for python

Comment: Hi, as you have now answers now, you may think about [accepting an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to reward the one that gives you the most helpful comment.

Answer (score 5):

You could use `zip` with different slicing of your values

- `values[::3]` iterates 1 over 3, so only names
- `values[1::3]` iterates 1 over 3 starting at index 1, so only ages
- `values[2::3]` iterates 1 over 3 starting at index 2, so only countries

```
values = ['John', 18, 'Spain', 'Adam', 12, 'Hungary', 'Eve', 50, 'Greece']
list2 = []

for name, age, country in zip(values[::3], values[1::3], values[2::3]):
    list2.append({'name': name, 'age': age, 'country': country})

print(list2)
```

You can also use `dict+zip` to build the dict with `keys+values`

```
list2 = [
    dict(zip(['name', 'age', 'country'], vals))
    for vals in zip(values[::3], values[1::3], values[2::3])
]
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to loop over the list in groups of 3 elements, and append one dictionary each time, not three separate dictionaries.

```
for i in range(0, len(list), 3):
    list2.append({
        'name': list[i],
        'age': list[i+1],
        'country': list[i+2]
    })
```

Also, you shouldn't use `list` as a variable name, it conflicts with the built-in function with that name.

Answer (score 3):

If you know `zip()` and that it loops over iterators in parallel, it is interesting to know that it can loop over on a single iterator in parallel, practically slicing the input into tuples:

```
lista = ['John', 18, 'Spain', 'Adam', 12, 'Hungary', 'Eve', 50, 'Greece']
it = iter(lista)
[adat for adat in zip(it,it,it)]
```

produces

> ```
> [('John', 18, 'Spain'), ('Adam', 12, 'Hungary'), ('Eve', 50, 'Greece')]
> ```

and then for the dicts you can either index the elements as `adat[0]`, etc. or have Python to assign them to a tuple of variables:

```
lista = ['John', 18, 'Spain', 'Adam', 12, 'Hungary', 'Eve', 50, 'Greece']
it = iter(lista)
[{'name':name,'age':age,'country':country} for (name,age,country) in zip(it,it,it)]
```

will display

> ```
> [{'name': 'John', 'age': 18, 'country': 'Spain'}, {'name': 'Adam', 'age': 12, 'country': 'Hungary'}, {'name': 'Eve', 'age': 50, 'country': 'Greece'}]
> ```

Side note: `list()` is a built-in function, so I renamed the variable to `lista`, based on `adat` :-)

(Side note2: `zip()` consumes the iterator, so `it` has to be re-created if you try both of these snippets together)

Answer (score 2):

Simple, readable way:

```py
lst = ['John', 18, 'Spain', 'Adam', 12, 'Hungary', 'Eve', 50, 'Greece']
ans = []
for i in range(0,len(lst),3):
    ans.append({'name':lst[i], 'age':lst[i+1], 'country':lst[i+2]})
print(ans)  #prints [{'name': 'John', 'age': 18, 'country': 'Spain'}, {'name': 'Adam', 'age': 12, 'country': 'Hungary'}, {'name': 'Eve', 'age': 50, 'country': 'Greece'}]
```

Answer (score 2):

A quick and dirty way to do it is like this:

```
list_1 = ['John', 18, 'Spain', 'Adam', 12, 'Hungary', 'Eve', 50, 'Greece']
list_2 = []

for i in range(0, len(list_1), 3):
    list_2.append({'name': list_1[i], 'age': list_1[i + 1], 'country': list_1[i + 2]})
```

Answer (score 1):

here is my take on the problem

```
list_ = ['John', 18, 'Spain', 'Adam', 12, 'Hungary', 'Eve', 50, 'Greece']
result = []

for index, item in enumerate(list_):
    try:
        int(item)
        dictionary = dict()
        dictionary['name'] = list_[index - 1]
        dictionary['age'] = item
        dictionary['country'] = list_[index + 1]
        result.append(dictionary)
    except ValueError:
        pass

print(result)
```

its pretty simple enumerate gives another variable which is list index, then I try to make item in list integer and that wont happen with those strings so it will throw ValueError and pass and continue untile it finds an int then it will create a dictionary and add neccessary items to the it and then add the dictionary to the list (also do not use `list` as variable because its python reserved? keyword?)

Comment: This works, but IMHO it's a most confusing way to do it. And it doesn't generalize very well: It won't work if there's more than one integer in each group, or if there's a name or country that looks like an integer. It seems like you were actively trying to find an obscure way to do it.

Comment: well if you say so. next time it will be even more confusing then LOL But if it sits it fits and mostly you wont make such lists that have to be sorted

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over the list over every three steps. An example to help get you started is:

```py
>>> for i in range(0, 12, 3):  # 0 = start value, 12 = stop value, 3 = step
...     print(i)
...
0
3
6
9
>>>
```

Similarly you can do:

```py
data_list = ['John', 18, 'Spain', 'Adam', 12, 'Hungary', 'Eve', 50, 'Greece'...]
data_dicts = []

for i in range(0, len(data_list), 3):
    data_dicts.append(
        {'name': data_list[i],  # The first element in a group of 3 (the name)
         'age': data_list[i + 1],  # The second element in the group (the age)
         'country': data_list[i + 2]  # The last element in the group (the country)
        }
    )
```

Also, you shouldn't name any variable `list` because it will override the built in python [`list`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists.asp) class